# On trying to download file from Node JS, In browser getting error as: Failed network error

Tags: node.js, box

I am trying to download a file located in my storage in box.com.

When user made a api request with specific id then i am getting file url related to that id from box.com and in node js again making another api call to get the file chunks and returning it to the client.

Process is:

User make an api call as: /api?id=123 to node js

In node js, I am getting file url related to id 124.

Obtained file url is: https://box.com/xyz_123

Using this file url, I am making again an api call to the box server and getting file as chunk by chunk and returning it to client.

When the file is about to finish in 5 seconds, then in browser it is showing error as: Failed network error.

Here is the way i am calling the box url to get file streams and returning to client side chunk by chunk.

```js
const creq = https.request(boxurl, (cres) => {
    cres.setEncoding('utf8');
      res.writeHead(cres.statusCode, 
        { 
          'Content-Length': cres.headers['content-length'],
          'Content-Type': 'application/octet-stream',
          'Content-Disposition' : cres.headers['content-disposition']
        }
      );

    // wait for data
    cres.on('data', function(chunk){
      res.write(chunk);
    });

    cres.on('close', function(){
      // closed, let's end client request as well 
      return res.end('Success');
    });

    cres.on('end', function(){
      // finished, let's finish client request as well 
      return res.end('Success');
    });

  }).on('error', function(e) {
    // we got an error, return 500 error to client and log error
    return res.end(e.message);
  });

  creq.end();
```

File download mechanism working very well in my system.

When i deployed code to remote server and checking, then only this error is appearing.

Can any one please help me on this. How to solve this.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi, Box.com has a dedicated API with various [SDKs](https://developer.box.com/docs/sdks). Have you tried using one of these?

Comment: I have tried to use box sdk, but haven't found any use of using box sdk to download file.
If you see below link:
https://github.com/box/box-node-sdk/blob/master/docs/shared-items.md

Box sdk is also doing same way.
In this sdk by giving file url, it fetches file chunk by chunk.
Instead of box sdk, i am using http request.

Comment: @MattLindsay If you have any solution / suggestion of using box sdk and fetching file in node js and return to browser, can you please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

To make use of the Box Node SDK you have to create a Box app in the Box Developer Console. Then you need to configure and authorise that app. An example can be found [here](https://mattlindsaysite.wordpress.com/2017/11/21/box-nodejs-sdk-authentication/)

You can now write your node app that uses the Box SDK to talk to your Box app / account. An example of how to connect it up can be found [here](https://github.com/matt-lindsay/box-nodejs-example/blob/master/app.js).

The code to download a file from Box can be found from Box's SDK documentation [here](https://github.com/box/box-node-sdk/blob/master/docs/files.md#download-a-file). But before you can download a file you will need to discover its File Id by using other SDK methods such as [getting a folder's items](https://github.com/box/box-node-sdk/blob/master/docs/folders.md#get-a-folders-items) or [search](https://github.com/box/box-node-sdk/blob/master/docs/search.md) for content.

The folder id of your root folder in Box is always `0` which is a good place to start when searching for various file or folder id numbers.